Reference Request for global Hölder continuity of solutions to elliptic PDEs
In the article by Littmann, Stampacchia and Weinberger (1963), the authors study regularity of boundary points to uniformly elliptic equations of open and bounded subsets of the Euclidean space. More precisely: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. Let $A \in L^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{n \times n})$ be symmetric and uniformly elliptic, meaning there exists $\lambda > 1$ such that
$$\lambda^{-1} |\xi|^2 \leq \xi \cdot A(x)\xi \leq \lambda |\xi|^2 \quad \text{for all } x \in \Omega.$$
Given a vector field $F: \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, the authors of the article work with the weak formulation of the equation $\operatorname{div}(A \nabla u) = \operatorname{div}(F)$ in $\Omega$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. More precisely, we call $u \in H_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ a solution to the equation $\operatorname{div}(A \nabla u) = \operatorname{div}(F)$ if and only if
$$\int_\Omega \nabla \varphi(x) \cdot A(x) \nabla u(x) \ \mathrm dx = \int_\Omega F (x) \cdot \nabla \varphi(x) \ \mathrm dx\quad \text{for all } \varphi \in H_0^{1,2}(\Omega).$$
As a prerequisite result, they cite the following theorem:
Theorem 2.4: Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a ball. Let $p > n$ and let $F \in L^p(B,\mathbb R^n)$. Then the solution $u \in H_0^{1,2}(B)$ of the equation is Hölder continuous in $B$.
As a reference, they cite the articles of Morrey (1959) and Stampacchia (1960).
My first thought was that they cite the following well known local regularity result of solutions to the PDE, namely:
Interpretation: Let $p > n$ and $F \in L^p(\Omega, \mathbb R^n)$. Let $u \in H_0^{1,2}(B)$ be the solution of $\operatorname{div}(A \nabla u) = \operatorname{div}(F)$. Then there exists $0 < a < 1$ such that: for every $U \subset B$ open and $\overline U \subset B$ there exists $C > 0$ (depending on $\operatorname{dist}(U,\partial B)$) such that
$$\|u\|_{C^{0,a}(U)} \leq C \|F\|.$$
I found plenty of versions of this statement in the literature (e.g. the book of Gilbarg-Trudinger), but later in the paper, they need a global estimate of the following form:
Needed: Let $p > n$ and $F \in L^p(\Omega, \mathbb R^n)$. Let $u \in H_0^{1,2}(B)$ be the solution of $\operatorname{div}(A \nabla u) = \operatorname{div}(F)$. Then there exists $0 < a < 1$ and $C > 0$ such that
$$\|u\|_{C^{0,a}(\overline B)} \leq C \|F\|.$$
The first reference provided (Morrey) only gave an idea of how to prove the statement, the second (Stampacchia) is in Italian and I cannot find a clear statement for the needed Theorem. Researching on my own, I did not find the needed uniform estimate in standard literature, the only reference I came across was the preprint Global Hölder Solvability of second order elliptic equations with locally integrable lower-order coefficients (Hara, 2024).
My question is: Can anyone provide a reference for the Needed Theorem in standard literature?
Thanks in advance.

I suggest you post this on MathOverflow.

The question was answered in this post on MathOverflow.
The result can be found in [1], Theorem 8.29. Note that the case $\Omega = \Omega'$ is covered at the end of the Theorem.
[1]  Gilbarg, David; Trudinger, Neil S., Elliptic partial differential equations of second order, Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften. 224. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. X, 401 p. (1977). ZBL0361.35003.
